# Renaming example Kibana dashboards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

Is there a way to rename the example Kibana Dashboards that comes with filebeat?
The [Configuration Dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-dashboards.html) and [Configuration Template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-template.html) do help in changing the elasticsearch index name and index name defined in the dashboard.

The default kibana dashboard, for example, is "[Filebeat Apache2] Access and error logs", my objective is to change it to [Customname Apache2] Access and error logs". I also want the change to be reflected in example visualization samples and saved search samples.

Comment: In Management > Saved Objects you can rename your dashboard and visualizations

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was looking more into the settings that can be performed from filebeat configuration file itself.

Answer (score 6):

I found it under

1. Navigate to your dashboard in Kibana
2. Click "Edit" button on the top right corner
3. Then you fill see "Save As" button on the top right corner
4. It will open a pop-up window with a "Title" text box and a toggle "Save as new dashboard", you can uncheck that toggle
5. Type your title and click "Save" on the pop-up window.

Elk stack 8.0.1

[image: Kibana Dashboard Rename]

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. The solution is less intuitive than one could hope.

In "Stack Management" there's a "saved objects" menu-item in the Kibana-section. Search and find your dashboard and activate the 'Inspect'-option in the 'Actions' item-menu for the dashboard in question. An 'Edit dashboard'-page will appear, where you can see - and change - the metadata for the dashboard entire. But, more importantly here, you can change the title. Then it's just a quick dash to the bottom of the page, where the 'save dashboard object' button awaits.

Tested with Elastic Stack 7.17